# Can't download page in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I want to download page (https://www.csfd.cz/tvurce/65871) in NodeJS, but I get just random data.

```
�}Ms�F������+i"��)�Jْ;�e���7�KM0��LƩ��]��Yg��b��
                                                   Ow7U��J�#�K�9��L
```

I thought it is just wrong encoding, but even size is wrong (downloaded page have 44K, whereas this file have only 19K. What's more surprising is that simple downloading it by python works good.
Python code:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.csfd.cz/tvurce/65871"
r = requests.get(url)
with open('pyth.txt','wb') as handle:
    handle.write(r.content)
```

JavaScript code:

```
const request = require('request-promise')
const fs = require('fs')
request('https://www.csfd.cz/tvurce/65871').then((html) => {
  fs.writeFileSync('output.html', html)
})
```

I tried also additional methods like `request.get` with parameters and so on, but still the same result. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use compressed option in request module, see example with request module (https://github.com/request/request).

You need also followRedirect and followAllRedirect parameters to automatically follow 301 and 302 redirection cuz your request is returning 302 :

```
 curl -X GET https://www.csfd.cz/tvurce/65871 --compressed -v -i

 Response : 302
 <h1>Redirect</h1>

 <p><a href="https://www.csfd.cz/tvurce/65871-kit-harington/">Please 
 click here to continue</a>.</p>
```

In addition replace your writeFileSync with standard writeFile function

```
const request = require('request')
const fs = require('fs')

request.get({
    url:'https://www.csfd.cz/tvurce/65871',
    gzip: true,
    followRedirect: true,
    followAllRedirect: true
}, function(err, response, body){
   if(err || !response || response.statusCode != 200)
   {
      // error case, do stg
   }
   else
   {
      fs.writeFile('output.html', body, "utf8", function(err){

         if(err)
         {
            // error do stg
         }
         else
         {
           // success
         }
      });
   }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried different things, different options and encodings, some parsers, and I didn't get it to work with `request` and `request-promise`. From the docs, I would say you aren't doing anything wrong.

I tried then a different module, `unirest` (`npm install unirest --save`), and it worked out of the box.

```
const unirest = require('unirest');
const fs = require('fs');

var Request = unirest.get('https://www.csfd.cz/tvurce/65871')
    .end(function(res) {
      console.log(res.body);
      fs.writeFileSync('output.html', res.body)
    });
```

Hope this is of help.

Answer (score 0):

Read the `Content-Encoding` header. It's most likely compressed, which would explain the size difference.